# knockout binding to drodown & json data

Tags: knockout.js

using knockout (new to knockout) , mvc c# .
I have a dropdown and want to populate the dropdown from knockout.
The knockout should make a call to my mvc via ajax. I have the following code.

```
<select data-bind="options: country ,optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value'"></select>
```

My Knockout js:

```
(function () {
var viewModel = function () {        
    var self = this;        
    self.country = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: rootDir + "/Home/GetCountry",
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {           
            self.country = ko.observableArray(data);
        }
    });
};

var pageVM = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(pageVM, $("form")[0]);
})();
```

MVC Controller:

```
     public IActionResult GetCountry()
    {
        List<Country> country = new List<Country>();
        country.Add(new Country { Value = "us", Text = "United States" });
        country.Add(new Country { Value = "uk", Text = "United Kingdom" });

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(country);

        return Json(json);
    }


   public class Country
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The json returned is:

```
[{"Value":"us","Text":"United Statesr"},{"Value":"uk","Text":"United Kingdom"}]"
```

I get the error in my chrome console as:

```
Uncaught Error: The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that you're trying to load a string representation of an array into the observableArray. That's the error you're seeing. You'll need to call JSON.parse on the data before it's added to the array. The second problem is that you're replacing the country observableArray with a new observableArray when the data returns. This will break your binding. Load the data into the existing array instead like `self.country(data)`.

```js
var viewModel = function () {        
    var self = this;        
    self.country = ko.observableArray();

    var data = '[{"Value":"us","Text":"United Statesr"},{"Value":"uk","Text":"United Kingdom"}]';
    setTimeout(function () {           
        self.country(JSON.parse(data));
    }, 1000);
};

var pageVM = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(pageVM);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: country ,optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value'"></select>
```